# Пагинация неверно формирует ссылку

Tags: wordpress

Сделал пагинацию на странице с новостями, при первом переходе нормально переходи на следующую странице но при втором url наслаивается как например /page2/page8 при переходе сначала на 2 а потом на 8 страницу пагинации. Сам сайт: https://xn----7sbbahbo3ahcibfq2aggb3c4g.xn--p1ai/informacija/novosti/vse-novosti/

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Архив новостей
*/

get_header();
get_template_part('index', 'banner');
?>
<section class="blog-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Blog Area-->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="site-content">
                    <h1>
                        <?php the_title();?>
                    </h1>
                    
                    <div class="arhive_container">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page'=>20,
                    );
                    query_posts($args);?>
                    <?php 
                    if ( have_posts() ) :
                        // Start the Loop.
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            ?>
                        <div class="arhive_post">
                          <div class="arhive_date">
                            <p class="arhive_day"><?php echo get_the_date('d'); ?></p>
                            <p class="arhive_month"><?php echo get_the_date('F');?>
                            <i><?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?></i></p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="arhive_content">
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35, '...' );?>
                            </p>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Читать дальше</a>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                    <?php
                        endwhile;
                    endif;?>
                    <div class="paginations">
                    <?php
                    //    Previous/next page navigation.                        
                 the_posts_pagination( array(
                     'format'       => 'page%#%',
                     'prev_text'    => ('«'),
                     'next_text'    => ('»'),
                 ) );
                        

                    ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!--/Blog Area-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="sidebar-section-right">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Blog Full Width Section -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Без format создается page/2/ вместо page2 что ведет в никуда

Comment: Удали нафик  format

Comment: Если в никуда - верни ссылки на абсолютные.

Comment: Так вот я не знаю как убрать этот слеш после page. Без него все бы уже работало

Comment: Не надо убирать слеш! Нужно вернуть то, что поломал.